# Do relativistic electrons have more charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, gauss-law

Gauss's law tells us that the total electric flux out of a closed surface is equal to the charge enclosed divided by the permittivity. When a charged particle is moving close to the speed of light it's electric field perpendicular to its motion is increased. If the net flux is greater than it would be at rest then does this closed surface contain more charge?  [image]

Comment: Pay attention to the "closed surface" requirement...

Comment: Listen to @dmckee - where do those increased electric field lines perpendicular to the motion come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The charge enclosed by a surface is really just the number of protons inside minus the number of electrons inside all multiplied by the charge of the proton (which is a constant).

If the electric field has a large density in one region then it has less in another so that total flux over a closed surface is still the net enclosed by the whole surface is still proportional to the charge enclosed.